# How to access chart in PowerPoint via VSTO?

Tags: interop, vsto, powerpoint, charts

I am trying to access charts in slides in PowerPoint 2007 via VSTO, and I am a bit confused. While the Interop provides a property `Shape.HasChart` which properly finds shapes that have/are charts, I can't figure out how to access the `Chart` object itself. I don't see a chart property on the `Shape`. Am I supposed to cast the `Shape` to a specific type?

Looking into the documentation, it seems that charts were not well-supported initially in Office 2007, but it's not clear to me whether there is a way to access the `Chart` and do things like change the title or the axis. Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the OLEFormat.Object of the Shape.

```
Graph.Chart aChart = (Graph.Chart) pptSlide.Shapes[1].OLEFormat.Object;
aChart.Activate();
```

I can do this successfully with Office 2003.

I goggled a bit and [apparently with 2007 SP2 there is a way to get a your shape object a .Chart property.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/06/15/creating-charts-in-word-and-powerpoint-using-newly-introduced-object-model-in-office-2007-service-pack-2.aspx)  I do not have 2007, so I can not test this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had come across the mention to the elusive Chart property, but have yet to find it! It took me a bit to figure out that Chart is in Microsoft.Interop.Graph - still working on getting it to work, but this is a great starting point.